# I took an error in my commandButton's style called "unrelated"

Tags: css, jsf

I have entered a code, here is the code

```
<h:commandButton action="#{loginBean.Onay}" value="GİRİŞ" styleClass="button">
      <f:param name="yetkiID" value="#{loginBean.yetkiID}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem is that it doesn't show my css text called button. And when I clicked with ctrl on to "button" show me all css classes with red Unrelated text.

Here is the image from my problem

[image]

Comment: Show the styleclass and how it is imported

Comment: I wrote that between <h:head>...</h:head> tags, and import this with <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="superfish.css" />, and I used resource/css folders.

Comment: Try giving it another name, for example mybutton.. and show the css please. Did you build and deploy after adding the stylesheet?